# Python: Mulitple yield statements in generator

Tags: python, yield

**Problem:**

How can I add `x.replace(".0",".")` to the function rem0.

I need to have two yield statements, but can only get one of them working.

```
def rem0(data):
    for x in data:
        yield x.lstrip('0')

lGrid = []

for i in rem0(grid):
    lGrid.append(i)
```

Comment: Why do you need two `yield` statements?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, do you want `yield x.lstrip('0').replace(".0",".")`?

Comment: @kindall I guess I don't need two yield statements, I just need both the x.lstrip and x.replace to execute.

Comment: you could use `lGrid = list(rem0(grid))` instead of `for`-loop and append() here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following construct will solve your problem.

```
def rem0(data):
    for x in data:
        yield x.lstrip('0').replace(".0", ".")
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Did not know I could write statement like that

Comment: Chaining the method calls like that certainly works and might even be what you prefer.  But if there are multiple transformations and each step's output has a logical name, you can use intermediates.  e.g.: `y = x.lstrip('0')`, followed by `yield y.replace(".0", ".")`

Answer (score 1):

You don't even really want a generator as the result is a list anyway, it's more efficient to just build the list straight off and write:

```
grid = [el.lstrip('0').replace('.0', '') for x in some_data]
```